# Find all polynomials s.t. $(x-3)P(x+1)-(x+3)P(x-2)=3x(x^2-9)$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: polynomials

> The question is to find all polynomials $P$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ $$(x-3)P(x+1)-(x+3)P(x-2)=3x(x^2-9).$$

I've tried putting in different values of $x$, namely those which are zeros of the R.H.S., but all I got from that was that $P(1)=P(-3)=0$.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Did you mean $P(1)=P(-2)=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer would be

$$P(x)=(x-1)(x+2)Q(x),$$ for some polynomial $Q$ that satisfies $$Q(x)=Q(x-3)+3.$$  First, note that $P(1)=P(-2)=0,$ by evaluating in $x=3,-3.$ So there must exists a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that   $$P(x)=(x-1)(x+2)Q(x).$$ Putting this into the equality, we find that $Q$ must satisfy

$$Q(x+1)=Q(x-2)+3.$$ After changing $x+1 $ for $x$ we find

$$Q(x)=Q(x-3)+3.$$  It is easy to verify that $Q(x)=x-a$ is valid for each real $a.$ Not sure if those are the only ones.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ LeGrandDODOM(see below) already completed this answer where I left it.

Comment: You have corrected your answer so I have removed my downvote. I have also added an answer that picks up where you left off.

Comment: Thanks!! I edited to point to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: (when you correctly get $P(1)=P(-2)=0$) you know that $P(x)$ has factor $(x-1)(x+2)$ corresponding to the two roots.

So set $P(x)=(x-1)(x+2)Q(x)$ and see what you can find out about $Q$

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\frac{P(x+1)}{x+3}-\frac{P(x-2)}{x-3}=3x,$$
we obtain $$P(x)=(x+2)(x-1)Q(x),$$
where $Q$ is a polynomial  and from here $$Q(x+1)-Q(x-2)=3$$

Answer (score 1):

Filling the blank in Magnusseen's answer.

By writing $P(x)=(x-1)(x+2)Q(x)$ it must be that $Q(x)=Q(x-3)+3$.

Taking derivatives on both sides, $Q'(x)=Q'(x-3)$. Either $Q'$ is a non-zero constant or we can consider $z\in \mathbb C$ a root of $Q'$. Then $Q'(z-3)=0$. Using this argument repeatedly, one finds that all the $z-3n$ where $n\in \mathbb N$ are roots of $Q'$, hence $Q'=0$.

To sum up, there is some $c\in \mathbb R$ such that $Q'=c$, hence $Q(x)=cx+d$ for some $d\in \mathbb R$. Plugging this back into $Q(x)=Q(x-3)+3$ and equating coefficients, we must have $c=1$ and $d$ in undetermined.

Conversely, $Q(x)=x+d$ fits the bill, no matter $d$.

Comment: Nice!! Already upvoted you.